# How do I avoid creating multiple python process w/ os.system?

Tags: python, process, exit, sys, os.system

When the 2 consecutive if statements executes, my python program shuts down. But that's not what I want. I want it to loop again and not exit the script. The problem that I found with simply looping is that python processes are created every time the `os.system(command)` line runs. I've individually tried the following:

`os.exit()`

`sys.exit()`

```
def kill_process():
    pid = os.getpid()
    sig = signal.SIGKILL
    os.kill(pid, sig)
```

All of those options were individually paired with a `os.system("python3 script.py")`, yet none of these did the trick. Every scenario simply exits the script.

How do I make it so that when `os.system(command)` is passed that it just loops again without killing/exiting the script and without creating another python process everytime?

Here's the function in question:

```
def bluetoothLoop():
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        BT_state = subprocess.run(['''system_profiler SPBluetoothDataType'''], shell=True, capture_output=True, encoding="utf", errors="ignore")
        BT_state = BT_state.stdout
        sound = "Blow"
        title = "TURN OFF BLUETOOTH"
        message = "-------------------------"
        if "State: On" in BT_state and not "  Connected:" in BT_state:
            time.sleep(1)
            BT_state = subprocess.run(['''system_profiler SPBluetoothDataType'''], shell=True, capture_output=True, encoding="utf", errors="ignore")
            BT_state = BT_state.stdout
            if "State: On" in BT_state and not "  Connected:" in BT_state:
                command = f'''
                osascript -e 'display notification "{message}" with title "{title}" sound name "{sound}"'
                '''
                os.system(command)
                os.exit()
                time.sleep(1)
                notify.restart()
```

Thanks a bunch, I've been struggling with this for a while now.

Comment: what do you want to do, exactly? run the `<command>` again? Did the old `<command>` exit?

Comment: Uh... what? You don't want additional python processes. Then why are you starting additional python processes?

Comment: os.system is inferior to the subprocess module, in terms of flexibility. Use subprocess for capturing PIDs, maintaining state, etc.

Comment: @JacobIRR was about to post that as well, plus it looks like they are already using subprocess earlier in the code, so they already know how it works (hopefully)

Comment: I should mention that I've a complete beginner, but you probably figured that out.

Comment: @Sören Because I don't know how to run the os.system command without creating python processes... im a real beginner.

Comment: @Esther, if I use os.exit() or any of the ones I mentioned, it exits the script. I just want it to kinda "restart" so that it reloops without creating a different process. How do I do that?

Comment: os.system will create a new process. The process will exit, all by itself, when it's done. If the process doesn't exit, that's the process's fault, and not something you can control in Python. calling any kind of exit() will exit *the script that calls it*. `os.getpid()` returns *the PID of the script it's in*, not of the new process you created.

Comment: `subprocess`, which you used earlier, can allow you more control over other processes that you start within python. regardless, it is very confusing what you are trying to do, and it sounds as if you don't really understand how os.system() works.

Comment: @Esther, yes I don't really understand it because I just started learning programming like 2 months ago. But thank you, I didn't know I could create a notification with subprocess as well. All I had to do was to replace ```os.system(command)```, ```os.exit()``` and ```notify.restart()``` with ```subprocess.call(command, shell=True)```. I think it works as intended now. Muchos gracias!